# Create a custom control in wpf for mahapps tile

Tags: c#, wpf, tile

I wan't to create a custom control for mahapps to make a customize tile control that have binding property for visual to make an icon inside the tile

control xaml code

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:iTile}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:iTile}">
                <controls:Tile Title="{TemplateBinding Title}"
                               HorizontalTitleAlignment="Left"
                               HorizontalContentAlignment="Right"
                               Height="100" Width="100"
                               Margin="0"
                               VerticalContentAlignment="Top">
                    <Rectangle Fill="Black" Height="45" Width="45" Margin="0,10,8,0">
                        <Rectangle.OpacityMask>
                            <VisualBrush Visual="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=Icon}" Stretch="Uniform" />
                        </Rectangle.OpacityMask>
                    </Rectangle>
                </controls:Tile>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

control csharp code

```
public class iTile : Tile
{
    static iTile()
    {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(iTile), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(iTile)));
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty IconProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("Icon", typeof(Object), typeof(iTile), new UIPropertyMetadata());

    public Object Icon
    {
        get { return GetValue(IconProperty); }
        set { SetValue(IconProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

and control use like this

```
<iControls:iTile Title="Some Title"
                         Icon="{iconPacks:PackIconMaterial Kind=AccountOff}"/>
```

but icon not shown just the title of the tile.

Answer (score 0):

You could set the `Visual` property to a `PackIconMaterial` in your template:

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:iTile}">
    <controls:Tile Title="{TemplateBinding Title}"
                               HorizontalTitleAlignment="Left"
                               HorizontalContentAlignment="Right"
                               Height="100" Width="100"
                               Margin="0"
                               VerticalContentAlignment="Top">
        <Rectangle Fill="Black" Height="45" Width="45" Margin="0,10,8,0">
            <Rectangle.OpacityMask>
                <VisualBrush Stretch="Uniform">
                    <VisualBrush.Visual>
                        <iconPacks:PackIconMaterial Kind="{Binding Icon, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" />
                    </VisualBrush.Visual>
                </VisualBrush>
            </Rectangle.OpacityMask>
        </Rectangle>
    </controls:Tile>
</ControlTemplate>
```

...and then set the `Icon` property to an enumeration value:

```
<iControls:iTile Title="Some Title"
             Icon="{x:Static iconPacks:PackIconMaterialKind.AccountOff}"/>
```

Comment: thank you for your replay but why icon not shown because may be I use material and maybe use other sources. how can I solve this problem

Comment: "how can I solve this problem"? Are you kidding? Read my answer again and copy it over to your project. It does solve your issue.

Comment: sorry i mean i want to binding the entire visual not kind

Comment: Why? This apparently doesn't work. So you could choose a solution that does work and give you the exact same results or you could choose a solution that doesn't work. It should be a very easy choice.